# How can I stop a postback from refreshing the page at the client

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, postback

When I start a postback using __doPostBack, a file is created and going back to the user to download in the `HttpContext.Current.Response`.

Because I change the `Response`, the page including its javascript values is not modified

But when I have no file to output, the page is refreshed (because of the postback) and the javascript modification on the page are lost.

How can I 'stop' the postback from continuing and persist my current page? I can't use an async postback, because I need the postback to let the user download the file.

**EDIT:** more info after some questions in the comments:

- The file is requested in a webservice request. The webservice needs
  to execute a heavy query to determine if a file will be created. I
  prefer that this only happens once.
- The user can drag / drop some filters that will be used in the file
  request. If no file is  available, the user should be able to change
  his filters, so thats why the page should not be changed.

Comment: The first that comes to my mind is(not tested): use a hidden button as [PostbackTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.postbacktrigger.aspx) for your UpdatePanel. In your serverside handler where you created the file(or not) so far, register javascript that `clicks` this button if you have a file. Handle this event and deliver the file. If there is no file, don't register the script.

Comment: It will work, but my problem is that the file is requested from a webservice. I don't know if I will have a file until the request is done. With your solution, the file would be created twice. Its a heavy request that can take some time, so I'd rather not do that twice.

Comment: Why do you need to create the file to know if it exists? That sounds rather odd. I would add a method to your webservice that checks this without creating.

Comment: The file is created in the webservice request, depending on the specified parameters. It's not an existing file thats popped out. The query to get the data to use for creating the file is heavy, and only after that query is done, I know if the file will be created or not.

Comment: Maybe i'm naive, but aren't the parameters deciding whether the file will be created or not? If so, the webservice should also be able to return a `boolean` if a file can be created from the given parameters without actually creating the file. The latter function should be called only from the full `PostbackTrigger` postback.

Comment: The parameters are used to execute a query. That query returns data or not, and that data is used for creating the file. You are right that I can add a bool function that returns IF a file can be created, but still the query will be executed twice, one time to determine IF... and the other time to create the file. I really don´t want this heavy query to run twice.

Comment: Maybe you should approach your goal from a different angle. Instead of trying to do this with a postback to the same page, what about putting in an iframe on the page, and having your button set the url on the iframe to a page that will download the file. Basically split the file download process into it's own page, and use querystring parameters for any info that needs to be passed to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the W3 standards and RFC 2616:

> 10.2.5 204 No Content   The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body, and might want to return updated
>   metainformation. The response MAY include new or updated
>   metainformation in the form of entity-headers, which if present SHOULD
>   be associated with the requested variant.
>   **If the client is a user agent, it SHOULD NOT change its document view from that which caused the request to be sent.** This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.   The 204 response MUST NOT
>   include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first
>   empty line after the header fields.

Note the bolded line here. I have not tried it myself; however, setting the HTTP status to 204 and sending back an empty document, rather than trying to stop postback entirely, is certainly worth a shot.

Good luck, I hope this helps.

EDIT: this is the code that does the trick: 
`System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 204;`

Comment: Amazing.. works great! Exactly the answer to my question without any workarounds